# Gitlab ci. How to configure the launch of only one task for each runner?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

How to configure the launch of only one task for each runner, so that other tasks queue up, and do not try to run at the same time, breaking the builds?

Im have 3 runners macos, in the config.toml it is indicated for each [[runners]] "concurrent= 1" "limit = 1"
When running 3 jobs, 2 jobs can run on the same runner, build crashes, 1 runner is left idle.
When start 6 jobs, all 6 builds fall.

I expect that when 6 tasks are launched, 3 tasks will be completed, 3 will be in the queue and will be executed when the runners are free.

I went through different options for the config file, but I still encounter this problem

I will add that I use one config file for three runners. could this be a problem?

```
[[runners]]   
  name = "Runner 1"   
  url = "https://your-gitlab-instance.com/"       
  token = "your-runner-token"   
  executor = "shell"       
  concurrent = 1  

[[runners]]   
  name = "Runner 2"       
  url = "https://your-gitlab-instance.com/"       
  token = "your-runner-token"   
  executor = "shell"   
  concurrent = 1  

[[runners]]   
  name = "Runner 3"   
  url = "https://your-gitlab-instance.com/"   
  token = "your-runner-token"    
  executor = "shell"   
  concurrent = 1
```

Comment: Welcome, please add the configuration to you question not under it in a comment.  And have you tried what happens when you have a dedicated configuration file for each runner?

Comment: @hakre, thanks, I moved the config file to the main post.

Creating a separate config.toml for each runner solved my problem, added as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that on a Mac were installed 3 services for each runner that used one common config.toml file, creating a separate config file for each runner service solved the problem.
Hope this helps someone.